# Realsense d435 Lookup would require extrapolation into the future

Tags: transforms, ros-kinetic, tf2, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

I am using a realsense d435 rgbd camera to capture the world around the robot.

I am performing coordinate transformation in the camera callback `pcCallback(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr& cloud_msg)` (in cca every 1 sec, just if a condition is satisfied..)

I perform the transformation with:

```
success = camTfListener->waitForTransform(REF_FRAME,SOURCE_FRAME,ros::Time(0),ros::Duration(10.0),ros::Duration(0.01),&error_msg);
```

I only continue with the processing if `success is true` (so if the transformation was successful - i assume...)

**But what i experience is**, that even if the transformation is **unsuccessful**, the function `waitForTransform` returns `true`. Is this possible?

**So i get in the same time**:

1)`success=true` and

2)`[ERROR]: Lookup would require extrapolation into the future. Requested time 1566215389.147320515 but the latest data is at time 1566215389.029921464, when looking up transform from frame [camera_color_optical_frame] to frame [base_link]`

Also since success was true, i my algorithm continues with image processing and i get lots of errors such as [`pcl::VoxelGrid::applyFilter] Input dataset doesn't have x/y/z coordinates`, etc...

Can you please give some hints how to solve this issue?

Remark: the camera works on 30 fps, i have also a `static_transform_publisher` running on 100Hz - that links the `camera_link` to the `end_effector` of the robot.

Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/331027/realsense-d435-lookup-would-require-extrapolation-into-the-future/) by [akosodry](https://answers.ros.org/users/35610/akosodry/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2019-08-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are few things you can try. First try using `ros::Time::now()` instead of `ros::Time(0)` in your `waitForTransform` to get the transform at the current time instead of the latest transform.

Also you can try to catch the exception instead of using success. For example with the following you retain the same functionality:

```
  try {
    camTfListener->waitForTransform(REF_FRAME, SOURCE_FRAME, ros::Time(0), ros::Duration(10.0),
                                    ros::Duration(0.01), &error_msg);
  } catch (tf2::ExtrapolationException &e) {
    ROS_ERROR_STREAM("ExtrapolationException: " << e.what());
    return;
  }
```

---

Originally posted by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) with karma: 1655 on 2019-08-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) on 2019-08-19**:
also you can catch the `tf2::TransformException` exception if you are transforming a pose via `camTfListener.transformPose()`

**Comment by [akosodry](https://answers.ros.org/users/35610/akosodry/) on 2019-08-19**:
Thank you, im trying in 5 mins i will report what i got

**Comment by [akosodry](https://answers.ros.org/users/35610/akosodry/) on 2019-08-19**:
@pavel92 Thank you once more for the help!

Out of 112 times the error did not appear :)